# Three-finger long press on touchpad opens Run dialog

Tags: windows-8.1, sony-vaio, synaptics-touchpad

This is bizarre, but completely reproducable: on my Sony Vaio Fit 15, long pressing three fingers on my touchpad brings up the Windows "Run" dialog.

I've looked through the Synaptics touch driver settings, and nothing seems to be there (three finger click is enabled, but requires me the physically click down on the touchpad).

Can this be disabled somehow? Perhaps with a registry setting?

Answer (score 0):

Evidently this is caused by a setting in the Synaptics touchpad properties:

[image: Synaptics touchpad properties for three finger press]

When the setting for three finger press is enabled, but the list of applications to launch is empty, the Run dialog appears when long pressing with three fingers.

**Simply disabling** the "Three-Finger Press" option was enough the resolve my problem; three-finger clicking still works as a middle click.

Comment: The "Select programs" dialog used to contain `iexplore.exe`. Whoever thought that was a good idea?!